# Plugin Access to When Files are Saved

Tags: php, modx

I have created a snippet that takes specified code and minifies it, but I'm looking to turn this into a plugin to streamline the process. I'm looking to have the code minify when I save a file, and create a new file in that directory with a new name. I have this working as a snippet, but I don't want to be writing files every time the page is loaded.

Is there a way to check when a file (in the Files Tab/Assets) is saved in ModX, and then execute a plugin? I looked through the existing System Events, and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 3 system events that may work for you: OnFileManagerUpload, OnFileEditFormPrerender & OnFileCreateFormPrerender. My guess would be OnFileManagerUpload.
Docs here:
http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/basic-development/plugins/system-events/onfilemanagerupload

Though it's important to note [the last time I checked] that even if a system event is listed in the manager and/or documented, they are not all implemented [i.e. won't work] - best to check on this in the modx forums or dig through the code to see if it actually exists.

Now, you are trying to do this from the manager or some front end form? 
In the manager attaching a plugin to the OnFileManagerUpload hopefully works. In the front end you may have to attach your plugin to one of the page rendering events either read the file's time/date or append/prepend a timestamp within the file itself.

[or if you are using formit, you can probably use a custom hook to get the job done as well]